# Detect breaking changes in Typescript

Tags: typescript, parsing, typescript-typings

1. We are looking for a solution to detect any braking change to types exported in .d.ts (like interface removal, changing property type, changing enum value, etc..). Do you know some tool for that?
2. If there is no such thing, is there a way to parse exported items from .d.ts to some js/ts objects so I could do the breaking changes checking on my own?

I found this tool https://api-extractor.com/ that works with typings and with help of this https://www.npmjs.com/package/@microsoft/api-extractor-model. I tried some parsing with that and I was able to work with interfaces and enums but for others like variables and type aliases it doesn't provide much help so in the end, I would have to parse it from a plain string as declared in the .d.ts file.

Edit 1:
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiRBPAtBAJYBGW8A3vAPTXwAuAFkQM7xhQB28JCTCAOQAKAWXgA3EDBZFknAFDx4IAB4AHZDHrs5LbaABmUDPSFSWcgFyVFS%20JyiIQ1vTCKcA5gG5bSqB%20d7NEReGB87BhA9AH5rEmRkTC5w%20ABfH1tVDS0dTj14AwTrAAooF3o3TwBKeABeAD54V3dveVT5eVBIWAQUdEx4LBYYMGp3UBUAOnoWcipaBmY2Dm5eRYRiSXgYBO1kA3X2NBg4Tm1JaVkFJSzNbTBdfRAjEzNpKxsIhydyytaI-yBTjBUIpJQLOAoSTAeDINT0K5QCC2dIdcF0KDAUAwkiZdR3XL5QrIEplJoVFoAGh41mBISkNQa5L%20Pna8gWTFY8ExwDYUB0iDUREw%20ARTkJFSg7j23H48ACnCkRDALHk9FwakEUXoIGAAEEWDIPA4SJgADwAFWpADFlCodZxefALY1avYQBcMgt3Nz4MAiAYDFIQGd7GpEPA1DsAFbgbQ%20nbIPYHHAEYhkRZQbRwIOnMBRQ6pwikcgXGRyAo7CPCERqjWCZAAITgUAA1i0AMKMLgBNhugTa3UGo0m822ITK1tm9Wa-bwIiCu7FIYjMaO1TTWZVamtkC4OczkBzhfZejLvDFshVeqU2yH4%20LrTntMlqryeoZQ-wARNlvtzxdj2UQAEx1N%20g76oaRDGlApogGa46TtO9YPqez6Xlg27wLu%204HPeBwnkuK6jOMG4zJhN53ihBGPmexFrhMm6Ye%20XhAA)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using a little type magic with `typeof import(..)`, however it does not check for equality between types that are **only exported**.  The reason for this is because `typeof import(..)` will only give us the types of values / functions / classes - not types / interfaces.   Therefore, the only way to detect a breaking change from a type changing is if a value / function / class used that type.  Of course, it wouldn't be a breaking change if you added an optional property, so we can simply use the `extends` on the two import types and check if the old version is assignable to the new version.  Here is an example of a positive check:

```
declare module "my-lib" { // this can be the NPM version
  export const defaultPerson: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  };
}

declare module "src/index.ts" { // this can be the live root of the current version
  export const defaultPerson: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    newFeat?: string; // non-breaking
  };

  export const foo: string; // non-breaking
}

// this adds a compile-time constraint on the generics
type NestedAssignable<T, F extends T> = never;

// in a different npm project in root of "my-lib" that references the "my-lib" version from NPM
type NoBreakingChanges = NestedAssignable<
  Pick<typeof import("src/index.ts"), keyof typeof import("my-lib")>,
  typeof import("my-lib")
>;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-JlV4gA)

Here is an example of a failing case (the new prop in `defaultPerson` is no longer optional):

```
declare module "my-lib" { // this can be the NPM version
  export const defaultPerson: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
  };
}

declare module "src/index.ts" { // this can be the live root of the current version
  export const defaultPerson: {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    newFeat: string; // BREAKING
  };

  export const foo: string; // non-breaking
}

// this adds a compile-time constraint on the generics
type NestedAssignable<T, F extends T> = never;

// in a different npm project in root of "my-lib" that references the "my-lib" version from NPM
type NoBreakingChanges = NestedAssignable<
  Pick<typeof import("src/index.ts"), keyof typeof import("my-lib")>,
  typeof import("my-lib")
>;
```

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEBbA9sArhBAiRBPAtBAJYBGW8A3vAPTXwAuAFkQM7xhQB28JCTCAOQAKAWXgA3EDBZFknAFDx4IAB4AHZDHrs5LbaABmUDPSFSWcgFyVFS+JyiIQ1vTCKcA5gG5bSqB+d7NEReGB8lAF8fCPl5UEhYBBR0THgsFhgwandQFQA6ehZyKloGZjYObl4yhGJJeBhkZG1kAxr2NBg4Tm1JaVkFJVUNLR1OPXhDYwhTcysbO3tHQNd3b194f0DOYNDwu04QAHcAMRAoehd6N08vGjoAIQAlAFEAQQBpAEkBAHFbKKxIbqTTaMC6bQGJpXG7ee72OT4EhwKAAazW8hi8lKTFYm2AwDYUB0iDUREw+HoRCcY1cUHcLW4-HgAUObjALHk9FwakEID0IGAbxYMg8DhImAAPAAVAA08BOyhU9BAnEJ8GlAD54ABeewgPo+bF0dybSZEAwGKSq7ScNSIeBqRoAK3A2lNjWa8FaaTwhFI5CYFwaICt3TA-PaOAIxDIEnMA3gBkaDuEIi5PMEyAeKPRngAwowuAE2HqBPyVUKRUQxVAJSBJbYhEQwKjJdzeT7qSN6AAKdKZbJq1QFIoASnlqJAuB9HZAXdJoP7ftjWDHmtltjnC57y5jAbH8k1XiAA)

You can see it even gives nice error messages:

```
Type 'typeof import("my-lib")' does not satisfy the constraint 'Pick<typeof import("src/index.ts"), "defaultPerson">'.
  Types of property 'defaultPerson' are incompatible.
    Property 'newFeat' is missing in type '{ name: string; age: number; }' but required in type '{ name: string; age: number; newFeat: string; }'.
```

Comment: Tried your solution and it catches almost everything. Thanks for that! Also, I had to add the opposite check where I just switched the two declarations (To check adding a required parameter to a function). It still does not catch the case when an optional property or function parameter gets removed. Any idea how to deal with that? Added link to the playground, see Edit 1

Comment: So adding the reverse check is not valid since it marks adding a new interface as a breaking change. So with the proposed solution, I am not able to catch adding a required attribute to an interface or type and removing an optional one.